# Line break "no line to end"

Tags: line-breaking

I would like to know how to force a gap say in this instance:

```
\subsection{$K\nsubseteq L$}<br>
[Line break here]<br>
In the next three results that follow, ...
```

Naively using `\newline` or equivalently `\\` gives the message "no line to end". I can understand the error message but I'm not sure how to get around it. Is there another command I could use?

I apologise if I've double posted, let me know and I'll delete it. THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There is no need of giving a line break command after a subsection title, in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try

```
\subsection{$K\nsubseteq L$}~\\
In the next three results that follow, ...
```

which should do the work for you. You also can redefine the `subsection` heading style in your preamble to add a `linespace` after it to make it automatic in all you file.

Here is how a `subsection` is defined for the `report` class.

```
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                 {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                 {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

In your preamble you should then add the following to modify it:

```
\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                 {3ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                 {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

You can customize the space between the subsection header and the beginning of the subsection by adjusting the value 3 in `{3ex \@plus .2ex}%`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force a line break, you could always create a new line and fill it with something blank, e.g.:

`\hspace{1 mm} \\`